# problems refreshing android listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm currently working on an Android app with two tabbed-fragments.  One fragment consists of a pre-populated list in a listview.  The other contains a dynamic list to be displayed in a listview.

I want to populate the listview on the second fragment from the list items from the first fragment.

**The Problem** 
1) The ListView on fragment 2 doesn't populate unless the underlying adapter is initialized by a dummy list.

2) Changes on ListView are not instant.  If I remove a list item from the list, the item still appears in the ListView on fragment 2.  But if I switch between tabs, I see the desired List.

**Here's the code:**

**Fragment 2**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstance) {
//      listEntries = new ArrayList<InterimOrderEntry>(0);
        listEntries = DummyListData.getOrder();

        view = (ListView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
        ListAdapter2 listAdapter2 = new ListAdapter2(orderEntries, getLayoutInflater(savedInstance), container);
        view.setAdapter(listAdapter2);

        return view;
    }
```

**ListAdapter1**

```
private void addToList2(String itemName, int quantity, int itemImageId, Context context){
        ListEntry listEntry = new ListEntry(itemName, quantity, itemImageId);
        listEntries.clear();
        listEntries.addAll(LisAdapter2.getOrderEntries());
        listEntries.add(orderEntry);

        new ListAdapter2().refreshListEntries(listEntries);
    }
```

**ListAdapter2**

```
private static List<ListEntry> listEntries;
public void refreshListEntries(List<ListEntry> newListEntries){
        listEntries.clear();
        listEntries.addAll(newListEntries);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the answer was in the android docs, here's the link:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html